# Are there any disadvantages to adding SOCK_CLOEXEC when I use socket()?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking

It seems useful to add the `SOCK_CLOEXEC` flag when creating a socket, but I am not sure there's any side effect in that.

In other word, can I always add `SOCK_CLOEXEC` flag when using `socket()`?

Answer (score 1):

`SOCK_CLOEXEC` is indeed a pretty cool flag which can be useful especially in multithreaded programs (see [open(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) man page).

It is important to say though that *it should not replace the explicit releasing of resources*. Even though using this flag will close the socket automatically, it is still your responsibility as a programmer and getting used to not-freeing your resources is a bad practice.